# Java Style: Catching a bunch of slightly different errors

Tags: java, exception, coding-style

In a program I'm working on in Java where I have to read data from a file. The data is formatted so that each line contains all the necessary information to construct a new object. When I parse the data, I have a block of code that looks something like this:

```
String[] parts = file.nextLine().split(",");

String attr1 = parts[0];
int attr2, attr3;
try{
    attr2 = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
} catch (NumberFormatException ex){
    System.out.println("Could not parse attr2, got " + parts[1] + ".");
    return;
}
try{
    attr3 = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
} catch (NumberFormatException ex){
    System.out.println("Could not parse attr3, got " + parts[2] + ".");
    return;
}
ClassA attr4 = null, attr5 = null, attr6 = null;
try{
   ...
} catch (SomeExceptionType ex){
    System.out.println("Could not parse attr4, got " + parts[3] + ".");
}
...
```

I find myself repeating the same simple try block over and over again. In an attempt to mitigate the situation and adhere to the DRY principle a bit more, I introduced some `attempt` methods:

```
int attr2 = attemptGetInt(parts, 1, "attr2");
int attr3 = attemptGetInt(parts, 2, "attr3");
ClassA attr4 = attemptGetClassA(parts, 3, "attr4");
...

// Somewhere in the class

public int attemptGetInt(String[] parts, int index, String name) throws SomeOtherException1{
    try{
        return Integer.parseInt(parts[index]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex){
        throw new SomeOtherException1("Could not parse " + name + ", got " + parts[index] + ".");
    }
}

public ClassA attemptGetClassA(String[] parts, int index, String name) throws SomeOtherException2{
    try{
        return ...
    } catch (SomeExceptionType ex){
        throw new SomeOtherException2("Could not parse " + name + ", got" + parts[index] + ".");
    }
}
...
```

Even this feels weird though, because there are a lot of different types I have to return that all sort of have the same but slightly different code and need to catch a slightly different error each time (i.e. I have to create an `attemptGetClassB` and `attemptGetClassC` and so on, a bunch of times with similar code each time).

Is there an elegant way of writing code like this?

Comment: Not really. Check out [PrintStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) and note how many print methods there are. Unfortunately, there's really no good way around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control over the format of the input file you might wish to change it to XML with a schema. That way the parser itself takes care of a lot of this type of checking for you.

However from the nature of the question I assume the format is fixed. In that case I would suggest splitting the syntax checking and parsing into separate steps for each line.

An easy way to do the syntax checking is using a regexp. Fairly complex syntax can be encoded in a regular expression so unless the files contain some sort of nesting (in which case DEFINITELY use XML instead) then it should be fairly straightforward.

The second step of parsing should then only return exceptions by exception :-) You still need to catch them but it's perfectly good form to gather all of your catches into a single block because it should only be used when debugging: in normal operations the syntax check will catch errors before this step.

My view is that this design is more intuitive and obvious. It may have a downside in error reporting if you specifically want to report on each error separately. In that case you'll need to break the string into substrings first (using a Scanner for example) and then syntax check each substring.

As a final note, opinions vary on this but my personal preference is not to use exception handling for conditions that occur in normal operations. They are not well suited for that (in my opinion). Better to do what I'm suggesting here: have explicit code to check error conditions before processing and then use exceptions for things that should not normally occur.